# WAMP apache httpd.config and hosts - how to alias localhost to port 8080?

Tags: apache, port, wamp, wampserver, portforwarding

Ok so I configured my apache installation on Windows 7 such that it listens on `port 8080` by changing the respective entry in `httpd.config`.

I was *too stupid* to realize that now I have to access localhost with `:8080` at the end.

**Question:** is there a way to have my box automagically resolve `localhost` to `127.0.0.1:8080` ? I don't like haviog to type :8080, and NO I *CANNOT* change the port to 80, I need that one for firewall.

Thanks

Comment: no. hostnames have nothing to do with ports. You'll have to specify the port yourself, or set up a proxy on the usual port 80 that will do the 8080 requests on your behalf. ... or bite the bullet and use port 80 directly and move your firewall elsewhere.

Comment: darn. wanna move your comment to an ANSWER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no. hostnames have nothing to do with ports. You'll have to specify the port yourself, or set up a proxy on the usual port 80 that will do the 8080 requests on your behalf. ... or bite the bullet and use port 80 directly and move your firewall elsewhere.